# Rationale for use of right-shift (rather than rotate) in SHA-2?

Tags: sha-2

The SHA-2 hashes in [FIPS 180](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf#page=16) define $\Sigma$ and $\sigma$ bijections of words, with $\Sigma$ used in the round function, and $\sigma$ used in preparing 48 words of [*message schedule*](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf#page=28) from 16 words of a message block. For example, in SHA-256 (using 32-bit words)
$$\begin{align*}
\Sigma_0^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 2}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{13}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{22}(x)\\
\Sigma_1^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 6}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{11}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{25}(x)\\
\sigma_0^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 7}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{18}(x)\oplus\operatorname{SHR}^{ 3}(x)\\
\sigma_1^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{17}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{19}(x)\oplus\operatorname{SHR}^{10}(x)\end{align*}$$
with $\sigma$ functions used in
$$W_t=\sigma_1^{\{256\}}(W_{t-2})\boxplus W_{t-7}\boxplus \sigma_0^{\{256\}}(W_{t-15})\boxplus W_{t-16}\;\text{ for }16\le t\le63$$
Notations:

- $\operatorname{ROTR}^k$ is right-rotation by $k$; it could be implemented in the C language as
  `uint32_t ROTR(int k, uint32_t x) { return x>>k | x<<(32-k); }`
- $\operatorname{SHR}^k$ is right-shift by $k$ with introduction of as many 0 on the left; in C
  `uint32_t SHR(int k, uint32_t x) { return x>>k; }`
- $\oplus$ is bitwise EXclusive-OR (C's operator `^`).
- $\boxplus$ is addition with truncation to word size (C's operator `+`).

There are similar $\Sigma_i^{\{512\}}$ and $\sigma_i^{\{512\}}$ functions for SHA-512, using 64-bit words and different constants.

**Question:** Is there a reason for the use of $\operatorname{SHR}$ rather than $\operatorname{ROTR}$ in the $\sigma$ functions of SHA-2?

Note: if we used $\operatorname{ROTR}$ rather than $\operatorname{SHR}$, it would still hold that $\sigma$ functions are bijections.

Comment: Here is explanation for Serpent's linear layer: _"Notice that if the linear transformation had used only rotates, then every characteristic could have 32 equiprobable rotated variants, with all the data words rotated by the same number of bits. This is the reason that we also use shift instructions, which avoid most of these rotated characteristics."_ http://cryptosoft.net/docs/Serpent.pdf

Comment: @LightBit: that applies to a _linear_ transformation. In SHA-2, the key schedule is not linear, thanks to the alternation of ⊕ in the σ functions, and ⊞ in the message schedule. Thus I do not think that the reasoning applies, at least to a comparable degree. Something on that tune would indeed apply if we changed ⊞ to ⊕, so perhaps the desire to better guard against an approximation of ⊞ by ⊕ may have been in the mind of the designers. $\;$ Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: @fgrieu actually I think he is spot on, from a paper describing attacks on SHA-1: "the linear code describing the SHA-1 message expansion is
invariant with respect to word rotation". The linear code being $\sigma$.

Comment: The followup on that, is that with modular addition the probability of a differential characteristic (for a specific attach on HMAC-SHA-1) depends on the position within the word, and rotating the characteristic doubles the probability. This type of attack would not work on the SHA-2 message schedule. https://eprint.iacr.org/eprint-bin/getfile.pl?entry=2006/290&version=20060824:195357&file=290.pdf

Comment: @Richie Frame: Indeed, the [message schedule of SHA-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf#page=25) is linear:$$W_t=\operatorname{ROTR}^{31}(W_{t-3}\boxplus W_{t-8}\boxplus W_{t-14}\boxplus W_{t-16})\;\text{ for }16\le t\le79$$and further a rotation in input translates to a corresponding rotation of output. Neither weakness holds for the message schedule of SHA-2, including modified to use only $\operatorname{ROTR}$. Still, reducing odds of the second property might be the motivation I'm asking for. $\;$ I guess that should be turned into an answer.

Comment: Things like SSE2 and MMX only have shift and not rotate.

Comment: @YuhongBao That statement may be true, however rotations can be done through shifting and OR/XOR. Also it in no way answers the question

Comment: `I guess that should be turned into an answer.` -- Absolutely! Which is why I'm bluntly taking the freedom to remind that answering your own question is very well a valid option. ;)

Comment: The question is somewhat answered in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/130). Replacing the third rotation by the shift makes the techniques used for SHA-0 and SHA-1 to build trails not work anymore. Whether this was what the designers intended, we'll probably never know.

Comment: Note to others: NSA designed it and the authors are unknown.